# Dart - General Summation Function For 'double', 'int', and 'num' Number Types

Tags: list, dart, types, iteration

```
mySumFunction(myIntList) = 
mySumFunction(myDoubleList) = 
mySumFunction(myNumList) =
```

Can a single function calculate all these above? Most functions that can accept `num or List<num>` as an input can also accept `double & int` and `List<double> & List<int>` as inputs as well respectively. Functions involving `.reduce()` though appear to be some of the exceptions.

```
sumList(List<num> temp) {
  return (temp.reduce((value, element) => (value + element)));
} //Only works with num type variables
```

Comment: The problem with [reduce](https://api.dart.dev/dev/2.14.0-165.0.dev/index.html#reduce) here is that it cannot return different types of values from those it processes.

Answer (score 2):

Code fixed for Dart 2.13:

```
// @dart=2.13
T sumList<T extends num>(List<T> temp) {
  var result = temp.reduce((value, element) => (value + element) as T);
  return result;
}


void main() {
  print(sumList<double>([2,3,4.5,5,6])); 
}
```

Result:

```
20.5
```

Comment: Error: A value of type 'num' can't be returned from a function with return type 'T'. Dart SDK version: 2.13.0. Thank you though

Comment: Code fixed for Dart 2.13

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are specifically looking for a solution using reduce, a forEach can be used compute the sum of nums ints or doubles in a function.

```
sum(List<num> list) {
  var total = 0;
  for (var x in list) {
    total += x;
  }
  return total;
}
```

A shorthand for this is the [fold](https://api.dart.dev/stable/1.10.1/dart-core/List/fold.html) function which is pretty much reduce with an initial value, and it solves the type issue. The following function works on nums doubles or ints.

```
sumByFolding(List<num> list) {
   return list.fold(0, (prev, element) => prev + element); 
}
```

Unlike the reduce function, fold is also safe to use for empty collections.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative:

```dart
sumList(List<num> temp) {
    return([...temp].reduce((value, element) => value + element));
}
```